# How do you link to a Rails partial from within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Here's my JavaScript, and I'm trying to re-render a div(without reloading the page) as a partial: _change_date_range.html.erb

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#end_date_string").bind("change", function() {
       var data = {date_string:$(this).val()};  // the value of input that need to send to server
       $.post('<%=change_date_range_root_path %>', data, // make ajax request
         function(html) { // function to handle the response
          $("#resultsContainer").html(html); // change the inner html of update div
         });
       });
     });
```

However, I'm rendering the default view in Rails like this, so the path needs the preceding underscore on the filename, whereas the JavaScript does not need it.

```
<%= render :partial => 'change_date_range', :locals => {:end_date_string => :params[:end_date_string]} %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your js to look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#end_date_string").bind("change", function() {
   var data = {date_string:$(this).val()};  // the value of input that need to send to server
   html = "<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'change_date_range', :locals => {:end_date_string => :params[:end_date_string]}) %>";
   $("#resultsContainer").html(html); // change the inner html of update div
   $.post('what_ever_you_need_to_pass_here', data, // make ajax request
     function(something) { // function to handle the response
      // do something else with the response ??
     });
   });
 });
```